# Flutter app not receiving notification from firebase in specific cases

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I have a flutter app that listens to firebase notifications in the foreground, using `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen`.

I could reproduce a scenario where the listener does not get invoked even though the device is receiving the token (I can see it in adb logcat, more on that below).

### Scenario 1

- Fresh install the app from android studio (app was not installed before on the device)
- open the app (app is now in foreground, and ofcourse firebase is initialized in code)
- send a firebase fcm notification from the server
- the notification is received normally by the app and `onMessage` is invoked.
- relative logcat part:

```
02-08 20:54:59.868  1266  1266 D android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service-lazy: WifiRequest::create vendor command to iface 31, vendor_id=0x1a11, subcmd=0x1200, res=0
02-08 20:54:59.868  1266  1266 I android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service-lazy: WifiCommand::requestResponse err=-14
02-08 20:54:59.868  1266  1266 I WifiHAL : wifi_get_link_stats: result=-1
02-08 20:54:59.869  1103  1205 E WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_5_Internal(l.1191) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown}
02-08 20:54:59.974  1103  2839 D AlarmManagerService: inside native alarm timerfd set Alarm Type = 2
02-08 20:54:59.975  1103  2839 D AlarmManagerService: inside native alarm timerfd set Alarm Type = 3
02-08 20:54:59.975 14787 18725 I AlarmManager: setExactAndAllowWhileIdle [name: GCM_HB_ALARM type: 2 triggerAtMillis: 258634626]
02-08 20:54:59.976  1103  2839 D AlarmManagerService: inside native alarm timerfd set Alarm Type = 2
02-08 20:54:59.977  1103  2839 D AlarmManagerService: inside native alarm timerfd set Alarm Type = 3
02-08 20:54:59.985 14787 18724 W ChimeraUtils: Module com.google.android.gms.gcm missing resource null(0)
02-08 20:54:59.990 14787 18724 I AlarmManager: setExactAndAllowWhileIdle [name: FcmRetry type: 2 triggerAtMillis: 258284640]
02-08 20:54:59.991  1103  2527 D AlarmManagerService: inside native alarm timerfd set Alarm Type = 2
02-08 20:54:59.992  1103  2527 D AlarmManagerService: inside native alarm timerfd set Alarm Type = 3
02-08 20:54:59.998 18477 18477 D FLTFireMsgReceiver: broadcast received for message
02-08 20:55:00.000  1103  1186 D AlarmManagerService: inside native alarm timerfd set Alarm Type = 2
02-08 20:55:00.001  1103  1186 D AlarmManagerService: inside native alarm timerfd set Alarm Type = 2
02-08 20:55:00.007 18477 18530 I flutter : newRemoteMessage.data: {data: data, requestId: 3197, type: disclaimer}
02-08 20:55:00.034  1103  2527 D AlarmManagerService: inside native alarm timerfd set Alarm Type = 2
02-08 20:55:00.034 14787 18725 I AlarmManager: setExactAndAllowWhileIdle [name: GCM_HB_ALARM type: 2 triggerAtMillis: 258634686]
02-08 20:55:00.035  1103  1425 D AlarmManagerService: inside native alarm timerfd set Alarm Type = 2
```

notice the lines

```
02-08 20:54:59.998 18477 18477 D FLTFireMsgReceiver: broadcast received for message
```

and

```
02-08 20:54:59.985 14787 18724 W ChimeraUtils: Module com.google.android.gms.gcm missing resource null(0)
```

### Scenario 2

- starting from scenario 1's last step, stop the app from android studio (recall it was launched in debug mode in android studio on a real device)
- rerun the app (from android studio or by simply tapping the app's icon using my finger)
- send a notification
- notification not received by the app (`onMessage` is not invoked), but as you can see from logs below it was received by the device but for some reason not propagated to the app
- relative logcat part:

```
02-08 20:00:18.752  1266  1266 I WifiHAL : wifi_get_link_stats: result=-1
02-08 20:00:18.753  1103  1205 E WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_5_Internal(l.1191) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown}
02-08 20:00:19.019   593   593 I BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceView[com.myapp/com.example.myapp.MainActivity](BLAST)#0](this:0xb4000075ade3a438,id:-1,api:0,p:-1,c:593) queueBuffer: fps=15.81 dur=1011.73 max=260.93 min=16.28
02-08 20:00:19.021   572   912 I hwcomposer: [HWCDisplay] [Display_0 (type:1)] fps:15.811406,dur:1011.93,max:260.75,min:16.30  
02-08 20:00:19.139  1103  1584 D AlarmManagerService: inside native alarm timerfd set Alarm Type = 2
02-08 20:00:19.139  1103  1584 D AlarmManagerService: inside native alarm timerfd set Alarm Type = 3
02-08 20:00:19.140 14787 16544 I AlarmManager: setExactAndAllowWhileIdle [name: GCM_HB_ALARM type: 2 triggerAtMillis: 255353791]
02-08 20:00:19.142  1103  1584 D AlarmManagerService: inside native alarm timerfd set Alarm Type = 2
02-08 20:00:19.142  1103  1584 D AlarmManagerService: inside native alarm timerfd set Alarm Type = 3
02-08 20:00:19.150 14787 15491 W ChimeraUtils: Module com.google.android.gms.gcm missing resource null(0)
02-08 20:00:19.158 14787 15491 I AlarmManager: setExactAndAllowWhileIdle [name: FcmRetry type: 2 triggerAtMillis: 255003806]
02-08 20:00:19.163  1103  5302 D AlarmManagerService: inside native alarm timerfd set Alarm Type = 2
02-08 20:00:19.163  1103  5302 D AlarmManagerService: inside native alarm timerfd set Alarm Type = 3
02-08 20:00:19.171  1103  1131 D BroadcastQueue: processNextBroadcastLocked, suppress to start process of staticReceiver for package:com.myapp
02-08 20:00:19.172  1103  1131 D BroadcastQueue: processNextBroadcastLocked, suppress to start process of staticReceiver for package:com.myapp
02-08 20:00:19.173 14787 14787 W GCM     : broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.myapp (has extras) }
02-08 20:00:19.188  1103  5302 D AlarmManagerService: inside native alarm timerfd set Alarm Type = 2
02-08 20:00:19.188  1103  5302 D AlarmManagerService: inside native alarm timerfd set Alarm Type = 3
02-08 20:00:19.189 14787 16544 I AlarmManager: setExactAndAllowWhileIdle [name: GCM_HB_ALARM type: 2 triggerAtMillis: 255353840]
02-08 20:00:19.190  1103  5302 D AlarmManagerService: inside native alarm timerfd set Alarm Type = 2
02-08 20:00:19.190  1103  5302 D AlarmManagerService: inside native alarm timerfd set Alarm Type = 3
```

focus at the line

```
02-08 20:00:19.173 14787 14787 W GCM     : broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.myapp (has extras) }
```

Question is why is this happening and how to solve it?
This is even happening for release versions of the app (the release versions are distributed through an apk and not playstore, and also the app in release version is runnnig in kiosk mode using airdroid mdm which prevents the app from closing, so the app is in foreground the whole time)